# Make ViewController become a listener of a button clicked, located inside a custom view which located inside a TableViewCell xib?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a ViewController which holds a UITableView.
I created a UITableViewCell class named - CustomTableViewCell and connected it to a xib file with the same name. Inside this xib file I have a custom view named - CustomTextFieldView, and this custom view has a button in it, named - listButton.

My goal is that the ViewController will be a listener of the listButtonPressed action so that later help me to expand and collapse the table view cell every time this button pressed.

This is what i have tried

But I got exception when the relevant button clicked

Thanks in adavanced

```
class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

   @IBOutlet weak var customView: CustomTextFieldView!
   @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
   
   static let identifier = "CustomTableViewCell"
   
   static func nib() -> UINib {
       return UINib(nibName: "CustomTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
   }
   
   
   override func awakeFromNib() {
       super.awakeFromNib()
   }

   override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
       super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

   }
   func configure(withCell cell : PTTableModel) {
       self.customView.initView(labelText: cell.label, placeHolder: cell.label, type: .name, hasList: cell.hasList)
   }
}
```

```
protocol CustomTextFieldDelegate : class {
    func didPressButton(button: UIButton)
}

class CustomTextFieldView: UIView {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var listButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var bottomLine: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var topLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var contenView: UIView!
    
    var delegate : CustomTextFieldDelegate!
    
    static let identifier =  "CustomTextFieldView"
    static func nib() -> UINib {
        return UINib(nibName:  "CustomTextFieldView", bundle: nil)
    }
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame : frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }

 
    @IBAction func listButtonClicked(_ sender: Any) {
        delegate.didPressButton(button: listButton)
    }
 }
```

```
class PetProfileDeatilsViewController: BaseUiViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, CustomTextFieldDelegate {
    

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var nextButton: UIButton!
    
    private var cells = ViewModel.createTableSction()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        
        headerView.initView(mainLabel: "Create", subLabel: "a profile")
        
        let vc = CustomTextFieldView()
        vc.delegate = self
        self.view.addSubview(vc)
        
        tableView.register(CustomTableViewCell.nib(), forCellReuseIdentifier: CustomTableViewCell.identifier)
        
    }
    
    func didPressButton(button: UIButton) {
        print("worked")
    }
```

Comment: Implement delegate in cell and do callback in your view controller.